# Bootstrap tag values not showing?

Tags: tags, bootstrap-tags-input

I have never tried to use bootstrap tags before and I am confused. All the documentation is pretty much the same code but I can`t get it to work? All I want to do with this code is show the values of the items selected when the button is clicked. I also want to be able to add and delete them but the code provided does not really show how to do this? The code I am using which is the only I can find is :-

```
<script>
var cities = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: 'assets/cities.json'
});
cities.initialize();

var elt = $('input');
elt.tagsinput({
  itemValue: 'value',
  itemText: 'text',
  typeaheadjs: {
    name: 'cities',
    displayKey: 'text',
    source: cities.ttAdapter()
  }
});
elt.tagsinput('add', { "value": 1 , "text": "Amsterdam"   , "continent": "Europe"    });
elt.tagsinput('add', { "value": 4 , "text": "Washington"  , "continent": "America"   });
elt.tagsinput('add', { "value": 7 , "text": "Sydney"      , "continent": "Australia" });
elt.tagsinput('add', { "value": 10, "text": "Beijing"     , "continent": "Asia"      });
elt.tagsinput('add', { "value": 13, "text": "Cairo"       , "continent": "Africa"    });
</script>
<script>
function myFunction() {

    var info=$("#input").val()
    alert(info);
}
</script>  

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

and the cities.json is

```
[ { "value": 1 , "text": "Amsterdam"   , "continent": "Europe"    },
  { "value": 2 , "text": "London"      , "continent": "Europe"    },
  { "value": 3 , "text": "Paris"       , "continent": "Europe"    },
  { "value": 4 , "text": "Washington"  , "continent": "America"   },
  { "value": 5 , "text": "Mexico City" , "continent": "America"   },
  { "value": 6 , "text": "Buenos Aires", "continent": "America"   },
  { "value": 7 , "text": "Sydney"      , "continent": "Australia" },
  { "value": 8 , "text": "Wellington"  , "continent": "Australia" },
  { "value": 9 , "text": "Canberra"    , "continent": "Australia" },
  { "value": 10, "text": "Beijing"     , "continent": "Asia"      },
  { "value": 11, "text": "New Delhi"   , "continent": "Asia"      },
  { "value": 12, "text": "Kathmandu"   , "continent": "Asia"      },
  { "value": 13, "text": "Cairo"       , "continent": "Africa"    },
  { "value": 14, "text": "Cape Town"   , "continent": "Africa"    },
  { "value": 15, "text": "Kinshasa"    , "continent": "Africa"    }
]
```

Sorry if this is a simply question but everywhere I go I get the same samples that don`t seem to work?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
var elt = $('#elt');
 elt.tagsinput({

  itemValue: 'value',
  itemText: 'text',
  typeaheadjs: [{
     hint: true,
     highlight: true,
     minLength: 2
  },{
     name: 'cities',
     displayKey: 'text',
     source: cities.ttAdapter()
   }
  ]
});
```